# Generate pdf from appended html content

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

I'm having problem with creating a pdf of html content

I want to convert all the content inside a certain div to a pdf. I've tried a couple of converters now but they only convert html-files. I don't want to convert the html-file because the user changes the content on the page with javascript.

```
<body>
    <div id="specificDiv>
        <!-- HERE IS THE CONTENT I WANT TO CONVERT -->
    </div>
</body>
```

I lack experience in this matter but shouldn't there be som simple way to run this on the client without installing something on the server?

I've tried: http://jspdf.com/ and https://pdfcrowd.com/.

jsPdf was in its early stages with html-converting and pdfCrowd just converted html-files(as I understand it)

I welcome all help and oppinions.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to convert the page that's edited by the user, you probably need something that uses Javascript. So - enter PhantomJS!

[Link to website](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used  http://www.tcpdf.org/ 
its really easy to generate a PDF with that.

See their Examples: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: I have a problem where I cant install plugins on my host. Otherwise this would be a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1.HTML2PDF http://html2pdf.fr/en/example

2.tcpdf   http://www.tcpdf.org

3.MPDF   http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: I will try html2pdf. I't looks like it runs on the client. The reason why I don't want to install plugins on my host is because I can't.

Comment: @Oscar,You want to create pdf without using php?

Comment: @Oscar,Then how to create pdf without installing a plugin like TCPDF in your server?Did you get a solution?

Comment: Im workin on it :). Found a tutorial on nettuts (https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/generating-pdfs-with-php/) where they are using http://www.fpdf.org/